# Подключение CSS и JS к JSP, выдаваемому через Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, servlet

Каким образом подключить CSS и JS к формируемому JSP, когда сервлет висит на корне сайта?

Если его повесить на любой другой адрес, тогда проблем с подтягиванием таблиц стилей нет.
Расположение файлов:

1. WEB-INF/view/*.jsp
2. styles/*.css
3. js/*.js

В обоих случаях путь к CSS и JS указан так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
```

Подтянуть таблицы стилей и скрипты можно так, но это не то, что нужно:

```
<style>
    <%@include file="/styles/style.css"%>
</style>
```

Вообще можно ли повесить сервлет на корень или это невозможно в принципе ?

Comment: а какой сервер вы используете?

Comment: Apache Tomcat 9.0

Answer (score 1):

Покажите ваш web.xml и я обновлю ответ.

Замапить сервлет на корень возможно. Простой и быстрый вариант - называете ваш war ROOT.war, кладете его в директорию webapps, удаляете в ней директорию ROOT и перезапускаете сервер. В web.xml должен быть мапинг сервлета на /.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hello.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал вот так: @WebServlet(name = "name", urlPatterns = ""). Если  urlPatterns = "/", тогда ничего не работает и по внутренним ссылкам сайта перейти не возможно, отсюда и невозможность подгружать CSS, JS и т.д.

Comment: вы не указали в вопросе, что у вас используются аннотации. следующий раз указывайте пожалуйста.